# Moving iCloud container to another Dev account

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I moved an iOS app  of mine which uses cloudkit from one developer account to another. No problems, however I realised later that you can't move apps which use cloudkit to another account.

However, I didn't encounter any issues, so right now the container is set up on one account, and the actual app is in another. So the question is as follows:

Is it possible to move your iCloud container to another account and if no, will it be deleted when my old account runs out?

Comment: The wording of your question is a bit confusing. I've just tried to transfer two of my apps, both of which use iCloud, to a new account. itunesconnect prevents me with "You can only transfer apps that aren’t iCloud enabled.". How did you manage to move your app between accounts? I suspect the answer to your question is the container will remain in place for users regardless of the state of your old account. You could write into the next update of your app a migration routine? I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486708/can-i-transfer-cloudkit-data-to-a-new-container