# Knowing when the watch app receives a push notification from Cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-watch, cloudkit

I have an app that has an Apple Watch extension.

Both use Core Data.

I have enabled, on both, the CloudKit ability.

I have configured both apps as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit?language=objc)

I open the iOS app, change the database, but nothing happens on the watch. I mean, the results are not updated on the watch.

Two questions:

1. Do I have to do something to push or to receive the notification from iCloud?
2. How do I know when the watch receives some notification from iCloud? Is that a way to debug this?

Comment: Do they both share the same iCloud container?

Comment: yes, the same container.

Comment: Is this related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407516/syncing-core-data-on-iphone-and-apple-watch?noredirect=1#comment136474734_77407516)?  If the watch app isn't embedded in the iOS app (ie it is independent) then you may need to set up your CloudKit container explicitly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478860/can-you-share-data-on-cloudkit-between-different-apps

Comment: I have deleted that question after you mentioned it. It was another point that also becomes solved by the solution I have posted here. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured both my iOS and Watch apps following 100% of what Apple wrote on the document I mention on the question, and the apps were not synching over CloudKit.

The solution was to modify `PersistenceController` to this:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
  static let shared = PersistenceController()
  let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
  
  var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return container.viewContext
  }
  
  init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MyApp")
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

    guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else{
      fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
    }
    
    description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    
    // Generate NOTIFICATIONS on remote changes
    description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    description.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "iCloud.com.myCompany.MyApp")

    
    if inMemory {
      container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Then remove the apps from your iPhone and Watch and run again. It will work instantly.